# Getting specific elements from arraylist

Tags: java, javafx

I have a resturant system using java fx, when a customer orders that order is added to the 'customer' class. The customer is then added to the 'table' class.

At the end im trying to display each individual customers order by looping through an array list of them and i cant figure out the syntax

an arraylist called allcustomers is set like this

```
allcustomers = tbl.getCustomers();
```

printed out it looks like this

```
[Customer{customernumber=null, customerorder=[burger'7.99]}]
```

**im trying to loop through the 'allcustomers' arraylist and just get the food items but im unsure how how?**

this is the full code

```
public class PaymentScreenController {


    public ArrayList<Customer> allcustomers;

    public Customer cus1;
    public ArrayList cusarray;


    private Table tbl = new Table();

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        allcustomers = tbl.getCustomers();




        // Unsure about how to do this for loop
        for (  : allcustomers) {




        }
```

any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: The answers on this question are giving me flashbacks to Stack Overflow Documentation.

Comment: Please post your `Customer` class (and any related classes; it looks like `Customer` may have a field called `customerorder` which is a list of some other class you have defined). No-one can answer this question without it; it would be better still to create and post a [mcve]. Without sufficient details, any answers you get are likely to be more or less gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

Enhanced for loops are used like this:

```
for (Customer customer : allCustomers) {
   //To display the customer's order or some other attribute
   System.out.println(customer.customerOrder);
}
```

With an indexed for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < allCustomers.size(); i ++) {
  Customer customer = allCustomers.get(i);
  System.out.println(customer.customerOrder);
  //This could be turned into one line, but shows how you index in ArrayLists
}
```

See the comment by LinuxServer below for a cooler version that uses streams to go through the list.

Comment: Good answer... might be helpful to show how to do it using a standard for loop as well in case the index is ever needed

Comment: do you know how i can get just their food order for each customer in the loop?

Comment: If you use `allCustomers.stream()` you can use `allCustomers.stream().map(Customer::getOrderedFood())` to map it. You can use `collect(Collectors.toList())` (returns `List<OrderedFood>` as Datatype) oder `findFirst()`/`findAny()` (returns `Optional<OrderedFood>`)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples for solving your problem.

**For-each loop**

```
for (Customer customer : allCustomers) {
      //...
 }
```

**indexed for loop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < allCustomers.size(); i++) {
  Customer customer = allCustomers.get(i);
  //...
}
```

**Streams (JDK 8 >)**

```
allCustomers.stream().filter(customer -> /*some condition here*/).forEach(customer -> {
  //...
});
```

I hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, Customer has ArrayList of orders nested inside of a Customer object. 
So, first you need to iterate over all customers in allCustomers 
and then iterate over all orders in customerOrder list. 
Star output is used to separate orders from each customer.

```
for (Customer customer : allCustomers) {
        System.out.println("*****")
        for(String singleOrder: customer.customerOrder){
            System.out.println(singleOrder);
      }
    }
```

Also, you can do it like this :

```
for (Customer customer : allCustomers) {
        System.out.println("*****")
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(customer.customerOrder));
    }
```

Comment: You should use technical terms and possibly explain them. "go through each order" can be done with "iterate over all customers". But it's okay.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Fixed it to be more precise.

Answer (score -1):

```
for (Customer customer : allcustomers) { // Iterate through all customers
  print("Customer Number: " + customer.customernumber); // Print Customer Number
  print("Customer Order: " + customer.customerorder.toString()); // Print the order array
}
```

Using a normal for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < allcustomers.length; i++) {
  print("Customer Number: " + allcustomers[i].customernumber); // Print Customer Number
  print("Customer Order: " + allcustomers[i].customerorder.toString()); // Print the order array
}
```

Comment: I cant seem to access these without creating fields in the customer class and these are incorrect as i already have them in their

Comment: To use your field just replace "customernumber" and "customerorder" to the correct field.

Comment: Never use public variables, make them private and ad an Getter/Accessor because public variables use too much memory. And for printing Arrays you could use `Arrays.toString()` Also is the variable called "allCustomers" an `ArrayList`

Comment: they are the correct field the customer class has customer number and customer order attributes and the customer is added to the table class. 'allcustomers' is assigned by getting all the customers from the table class. So how do i access these?

Comment: You can retrieve the variables with the public modifier via `customer.variable` (not recommended because public variables take up too much memory.) or via a getter/accessor with `customer.getVariable()`. If you think you know how to read the values from the list, you should look at the answers again.

Comment: @LinuxServer "public variables use too much memory". I'm not sure I've ever seen that before - there are very many reasons not to use public mutable fields in a class. The primary one is that they break encapsulation and make it impossible for a class to enforce invariants. Even if the statement about memory use is true (I can't see a reason why it would be, but maybe I'm missing something), this is surely far more important.

Comment: @LinuxServer That said "Never use public variables" is pretty much very good advice.