# java.lang.NullPointerException? When assigning get method to an arraylist

Tags: java

Hi im trying to display customer orders that are added to a 'table' class from another class

```
public class PaymentScreenController {


    public ArrayList<Customer> allcustomers; // Defining allcustomers Arraylist




    public Table tbl; // Creating instance of Table class


    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        allcustomers = tbl.getCustomers(); // Error seems to come from here when i assign allcustomers to the getcustomers method of table
        System.out.println(tbl.getCustomers());

        System.out.println("test");
        for (Customer customer : allcustomers) {

            System.out.println(customer.getCustomerorder());
        }


    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated thanks

** More code*

```
public void submitorder(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws IOException {
        //create a new UNIQUE customer to store that customers menu items
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        //add items to customer
        cust.getCustomerorder().addAll(order);
        // Adds the customer order to the table class
        tbl.getCustomers().add(cust);
        System.out.println(tbl.getCustomers());
        //clear menu choices screen
        lvOrder.getItems().clear();

        // Once added the desired number of customers move to next screen
        //extra customer was being added as a customer was put into the ArrayLust after the check happened.
        if (tbl.getCustomers().size() == noOfDiners) {
            Window mainWindow = btnSubmitOrder.getScene().getWindow();
            Parent newRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("payment_screen.fxml"));
            mainWindow.getScene().setRoot(newRoot);
        }

    }
```

So the customer adds stuff to their order, and then the customer is added to the table class

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Isn't it the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105027/getting-specific-elements-from-arraylist/

Answer (score 1):

If an NPE raise at the line that you have mentioned in your comment, that means, 
when the method `initialize()` is called, variable `tbl` is not instantiated and hold `null` value.

And when you call `tbl.getCustomers()` it causes NullPointerException, since `tbl` is null here.

I don't see any code, that creates the object of Table and assigns it to the variable. Maybe it happens somewhere outside this class since your variable has `public` modifier, then please, make sure that this code called earlier than the `initialize` method.

You need to create an object of `Table`, like:

```
public Table tbl = new Table(..);
```

For the more, specific answer, please, share your Stack Trace here.

Comment: Its added to in another class heres more code

Answer (score 0):

```
public Table tbl; // Creating instance of Table class
```

Here, you just declared your Table and not create an instance of it.

To do that you must do `tbl = new Table(insert arguments here);`

That's why you have a null pointer

Comment: Hi But i add to the table class in another class, ive tried creating a new table here but becuase of that it makes a new empty one

Comment: If you add to the table in another class, it's another instance of the class Table.
You can consider that the table in the class A where you put elements in it is another table than the one present in PayementScreenController

Comment: Ah ok what arguements would be the parameters there then?
Ive tried public Table tbl = new Table(); but i just get an empty table returned?